# Python3: send email using string representation

Tags: python-3.x, smtp, smtplib

I have instances of `email.message.EmailMessage` and able to represent it to a string (using `msg.as_string()`). That lets me to send such instance to another python program.

I'm wondering if there's a way to send email using that string representation. Something like:

```
send_email(msg.as_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well Not clearly Understood using String Representation but here is my way.

```
import smtplib  #import SMTP lib

ss = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)   #connect with GOOGLE SMTP

ss.starttls()                               #startServices
ss.login("Enter your Email id", "Enter your password")               #Enter Login Details

msg = "this is a testmail"                           #message you would like to attach      
ss.sendmail("Your Email id", "id you would like to send", msg)  
ss.quit()
```

Comment: Instance of EmailMessage already has `From` and `To` headers (prepared using `email.headerregistry.Address`). And my code is fine with sending instance of `EmailMessage`. But I'm looking for a way to send a mail using str representation of `EmailMessage` instance (`msg.as_string`).